# Area under two curves and between two curves are equal.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, area

In the accompanying figure, y=f(x) is the graph of a one to one continuous function f. At each point P on the graph of y=2x^2, assume that the areas OAP and OBP are equal. Here PA, PB are the horizontal and vertical segments. Determine the function f.
[image: Link to the question diagram]

Now my approach is this:
First area under $y=2x^2$ and $y=x^2$ at a point x is $x^3/3$. Now we need area $OAP$. If we rotate the axes by π/2 radians and reflect the rotated graph about the y axis, we should still preserve the area of the region OAP.

So, first we rotate the axes by π/2 radians and get the equation of $y=2x^2$ and $y=f(x)$ in the rotated system as

$y=\sqrt{\frac{-x}{2}}$ and
$y=f^{-1}(-x)$

Now to reflect the graph about the y-axis, we replace x with -x to get the transformed equations as

$y=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}$---(1) and $y=f^{-1}(x)$---(2)

Now we need to find the area under the two curves (1) and (2) from 0 to f(x).

So we have

Area $OAP = \int_{t=0}^{f(x)}{\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}}-f^{-1}(t) dt}$

Since Area $OAP = x^3/3$, upon differentiating we have

$\sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{2}} - (x-f^{-1}(0)) = x^2$.

Thus we have $f(x)= 2(x^2+x-f^{-1}(0))^2$
And from the figure, and the fact that area OPB tends to 0 as x tends to 0, $f^{-1}(0)=0$

Im unable to find the mistake here, and would be grateful to anyone that could point it out.

Comment: The correct answer is $f(x) = \frac{32x^2}{9}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area equation should be set up, instead, as

$$A_{OAP}=\frac13 x^3 = \int_{0}^{2x^2}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}}-f^{-1}(t) \right)\ dt}
$$
which, after differentiation, yields
$$x^2=4x \left[x-f^{-1}(2x^2) \right]
$$
or $ f^{-1}(2x^2)  =\frac34x$. Solve to obtain $f(x)=\frac{32}9x^2$.

Comment: Yeah, I realised i put incorrect limits after way too long. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

By a polynomic reasoning $f(t)$ should be of the form $f(t)=Ax^2$ because of the equalities when integrating for all $x$ (*it cannot be logarithmic, nor trigonometric, et al*). So we have to calculate the constant $A$. In the attached figure we have three equal areas $OMB=OBP=OPA=\dfrac{x^3}{3}$. Besides $At^2=2x^2$ so $t=\sqrt{\frac{2}{A}}x$. Therefore the equation
$$\int_0^xf(t)dt-\int_t^x(f(t)-2x^2)dt=3(\dfrac{x^3}{3})=x^3$$
$$\left[\frac{At^3}{3}\right]_0^x-\left[\frac{At^3-2x^2t}{3}\right]_t^x=x^3\Rightarrow2x^3+\dfrac23\sqrt{\frac{2}{A}}x^3-2\sqrt{\frac{2}{A}}x^3=x^3$$ Then $\dfrac43\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{A}}=1$ from which $A=\dfrac{32}{9}$.

[image]